# Unable to delete record from Solr if any white space there in PHP

Tags: php, solr

```
$cat = 'tv - Episode';
$user_id = 1;
$delsolrobj = new SolrFunctions();
$delsolrobj->deleteSolrQuery("cat: ".$cat." AND sku:" . $user_id . " AND content_id:" . $_REQUEST['movie_id'] . " AND stream_id:" . $epData->id);
```

I have posted my solr delete PHP code. Above code I am getting this error message in my page.

```
'400' Status: Bad Request
```

I am sure that problem coming from `$cat` because there are some spaces.

I Googled found one solution they are saying to put your category within braces. I have done with this code:

```
$delsolrobj->deleteSolrQuery("cat: (".$cat.") AND sku:" . $user_id . " AND content_id:" . $_REQUEST['movie_id'] . " AND stream_id:" . $epData->id);
```

Now in my above line code working fine without any error message. But my record not delete from Solr.

please help me.

Comment: Try this:- `<?php

$cat = 'tv - Episode';
$user_id = 1;
$movie_id = $_REQUEST['movie_id'];
$stream_id = $epData->id;
$delsolrobj = new SolrFunctions();
$delsolrobj->deleteSolrQuery("cat:'$cat' AND sku:$user_id AND content_id:$movie_id AND stream_id:$stream_id");`

Comment: @AlivetoDie Same error coming. `'400' Status: Bad Request`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query: (You can also use quotes when space is there)

```
$delsolrobj->deleteSolrQuery("cat:'".$cat."' AND sku:" . $user_id . " AND content_id:" . $_REQUEST['movie_id'] . " AND stream_id:" . $epData->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the values properly, so that even if there is spaces or quotes, you don't run a badly generated query (i.e. if a category suddenly had `' OR -cat:foo` or something similar in it).

If you're not using a Solr library (which should have an escape function available, you can use the ad hoc version:

```
function escapeSolrValue($string)
{
    $match = array('\\', '+', '-', '&', '|', '!', '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', '^', '~', '*', '?', ':', '"', ';', ' ');
    $replace = array('\\\\', '\\+', '\\-', '\\&', '\\|', '\\!', '\\(', '\\)', '\\{', '\\}', '\\[', '\\]', '\\^', '\\~', '\\*', '\\?', '\\:', '\\"', '\\;', '\\ ');
    $string = str_replace($match, $replace, $string);

    return $string;
}
```